# Is it necessary to use the comma in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Do I have to use the comma before the WHEN CLAUSE in the following sentence?
"We were swimming in the lake, when suddenly a crocodile attacked us."

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of necessity; it's a matter of whether you wish to conform to the style recommended in your manual of style.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which recommends that dependent clauses that follow an independent clause be set off by a comma if and only if the dependent clause is non-restrictive, i.e, if it's informational only instead of definitional.

Your example seems non-restrictive:  you've merely added an interesting story to your swimming holiday.  Here's a restrictive example:

> Do you remember that swimming holiday when a crocodile suddenly
>   attacked us?

Now the clause distinguishes that time when you went swimming from all the other, less eventful times.  So no comma.

Punctuation is a matter of style, not a matter of life and death, like swimming in a crocodile-infested lake.

Comment: Similar to your "distinguishing that swimming trip from others (and hence no comma)" point - if the OP's question is in response to the question "what were you doing when the crocodile attacked you?", then I think the comma should be omitted.

Comment: @deadrat Your explantion is very clear. So the point is to separate the non-defining (dependent) clause from the independent clause with a comma when it (the dependent clause) gives only additional information. Right?

Comment: @midomido Right.